# Using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to replace 5 drop-down boxes in a form for a datetime field (that was auto-generated with scaffolding) with the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker gem](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

How can I replace the following:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date %><br>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>
```

With this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following and it doesn't appear to show the datepicker:

Complete form:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>

<% if @transaction.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@transaction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this transaction from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :amount %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
</div>
<div class="field" id='datetimepicker1'>
  <%= f.label :date %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :date, class: 'form-control datepicker', id: 'datetimepicker1', placeholder: 'dd-mm-rrrr' %>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Complete form:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>

<% if @transaction.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@transaction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this transaction from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :amount %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date %><br>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Comment: Use a text field for the date input when using the datepicker so it reads it correctly.  Then just be wary of the format the date is being submitted in and adjust accordingly either via the datepicker.js options or via params submitted in your controller.

Comment: @bkunzi01 That's what I've tried. I've added the code I've tried in the OP.

Comment: and you javascript code?

Comment: @inye $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
      });

Comment: put inside of document ready the datetimepicker declaration `$( document ).ready(function() { $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(); });`

Comment: @inye That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you edit your `Complete form` to the code with timepicker part you are trying?

Comment: @inye Sure. Have done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127841/discussion-between-inye-and-bhav).